# Best way to rename a SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to replace a SalesResults table with a new version containing latest calculated results.

I guess the following would only take a few milliseconds for SQL Server to do but is it safe for any users accessing the SalesResults table at that time?

If not, it should I enclose the following in BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT in order for it to be?

```
DROP TABLE dbo.SalesResults; 
EXEC sp_rename 'SalesResultsNew', 'SalesResults'
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25828/the-best-way-to-rename-the-tables-after-development-completed

Comment: "DROP TABLE cannot be used to drop a table that is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. ..." [Ref](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this during off hours or a maintenance period just to be safe

```
Begin Transaction

Drop Table dbo.SalesResults
Exec sp_rename 'SalesResultsNew', 'SalesResults'

Commit Transaction
```

This assumes that the SalesResultsNew table already exists.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's designed to be a 24x7 global website with that results-refresh process occuring once per day. So I take it a Begin Transaction would protect users from a 'table doesn't exist' error?

Comment: Essentially yes by making them wait until the transaction was done

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on a consistent basis (and it sounds like you are), I'd use a synonym instead. So your actual tables would be called something like `dbo.SalesResults_20170108` and you'd do something like:

```
create synonym dbo.SalesResults for dbo.SalesResults_20170108;
```

Each day, you'd move the synonym to point to the new SalesResults table when it's ready.

Comment: Didn't even know about this, nor have tried. Learn something new everyday +1

Comment: I imagine the OP will still have to use a transaction to drop the old synonym and establish the new.  But of course, this should be much faster.